# InputPath syntax for SparkContext textFile

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Please tell how do I need to specify input path for `textFile()` with **SparkContext**. Like the below which does not work for me.

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/home/myFiles/sampleFile")
```

In this, 54310 is the port number specified in `core-site.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple error. Extension is required for the files we load in Spark Context

sc.textFile(hdfs://localhost:54310/home/myFiles/sampleFile.txt")

Comment: No, with or without extension works. HDFS is extension agnostic.